# Can’t update system with “sudo apt update” on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I got next error while updating with “`sudo apt update`”. If someone know how to fix this problem, I'll be thankful

```
it:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease               
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [90.7 kB]      
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease   
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: PPAs or *Personal Package Archives* are 3rd party software sources, and all security checks are on you to perform. Did you perform any?  As a quick look at https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  (*taken from your provided error messages*) shows no support for releases beyond 22.04/jammy.